# proper way to handle system locale change

Tags: android, locale

While user is running my app (bundled with proper translated string resources) and presses Home and switches system locale. I would like to change all string to his/her languages when he/she resumes my app. What would be the proper way to handle such change?

Answer (score 0):

If you've set up your project properly then you shouldn't have to do anything manually.

Make sure you follow this example:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html

if you create your proper strings.xml files for the different locales then the Android platform should automatically load the appropriate strings file based on the phone locale.